# How to define map function for a discriminated union with units of measure

Tags: f#

I created two units-of-measures, USD and EUR. I wanted to distinguish them at runtime, so I defined the following discriminated union. Then, I want to define the map function like this:

```
[<Measure>] type USD
[<Measure>] type EUR
type CurrencyKind =
    | CurrencyUsd of decimal<USD>
    | CurrencyEur of decimal<EUR>

    member this.Map<[<Measure>] 'currency> (f : decimal<'currency> -> decimal<'currency>) =
        match this with
        | CurrencyUsd x -> f x
        | CurrencyEur x -> f x
```

However, when I do this, I get the following error under `'currency`:

> FS0660 F# This code is less generic than required by its annotations
>   because the explicit type variable could not be generalized.
>   It was constrained to be 'USD'.

and under `x` of `CurrencyEur x -> f x`:

> FS0001 F# The unit of measure 'USD' does not match the unit of measure 'EUR'

Is there any good way to make this build?

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to accomplish, but perhaps this can be of some help: https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/units-of-measure/

Comment: Are you looking for a converter function f? From EUR to USD and vice versa? `Map` usually means a table lookup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you define the generic function, the *caller* of the `map` function defines what the unit is, but that's not right - you want the `map` function itself to define what the units are depending on the value. This can be done using interfaces, but it gets ugly.

In this case, I think you could quite nicely solve this by defining a new unit type, say `Money`:

```
[<Measure>] type Money
```

The function that you pass as an argument to `map` takes some amount of money and returns some other amount of money, so you can give it a type `decimal<Money> -> decimal<Money>`. Whether money is USD or EUR, that's something the `map` function can decide. In the implementation, we simply convert USD or EUR to Money before calling `f` and then convert back:

```
let map (f : decimal<Money> -> decimal<Money>) input =
  match input with
  | CurrencyUsd x -> CurrencyUsd((f (x * 1M<Money/USD>)) * 1M<USD/Money>)
  | CurrencyEur x -> CurrencyEur((f (x * 1M<Money/EUR>)) * 1M<EUR/Money>)
```

This probably gives you the safety you wanted. If we calculate `m + m`, that works because the unit is still money, but if you calculate `m * m`, you get a compile-time error:

```
CurrencyUsd(10.M<_>) |> map (fun m -> m + m)
CurrencyUsd(10.M<_>) |> map (fun m -> m * m) // Type error!
```

For the record, the ugly version using interfaces would look like this:

```
type Mapper = 
  abstract Apply<[<Measure>] 'm> : decimal<'m> -> decimal<'m>

let map (f : Mapper) input =
  match input with
  | CurrencyUsd x -> CurrencyUsd(f.Apply x)
  | CurrencyEur x -> CurrencyEur(f.Apply x)

CurrencyUsd(10.M<_>) |> map { new Mapper with member x.Apply m = m + m } 
CurrencyUsd(10.M<_>) |> map { new Mapper with member x.Apply m = m * m }
```